# Transform a time series matrix into ggplot format

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, formatting

How could I transform a time series matrix in the form of

```
      dDomingo  dSegunda     dTerça   dQuarta    dQuinta    dSexta    dSábado
[1,] -1.783558 0.5123224  0.5997068 0.4680476  0.6521374 0.6276698 -1.0763264
[2,] -1.730086 0.8552685  0.6426731 0.6377859  0.3995325 0.2944567 -1.0996309
[3,] -1.503333 0.9450167 -0.4125656 0.8446433  0.6839187 0.5397113 -1.0973919
[4,] -1.720261 0.3044134  0.6722075 0.5313041  0.6411365 0.7105043 -1.1393050
[5,] -1.234701 0.9189446  0.9670409 0.8713827 -1.1208727 0.3465987 -0.7483936
```

Into this

```
           V1     V2
[1,] -1.783558 dDomingo        
[2,]  0.5123224 dSegunda 
[3,]  0.5997068 dTerça 
[4,]  0.4680476 dQuarta
[5,]  0.6521374 dQuinta 
[6,]  0.6276698 dSexta 
[7,] -1.0763264 dSábado
[8,] -1.730086  dDomingo
```

... and so on until

```
[35,] -0.7483936  dSábado
```

Notice that the new data format I would like has only two columns. The first one will contain the variables values from the last matrix. The second column will contain the respective column where the variable values was.

The time series matrix data is the following:

```
structure(c(-1.78355763661757, -1.73008589314791, -1.50333251627705, 
-1.72026078275706, -1.23470060199216, 0.512322374645035, 0.855268450002498, 
0.945016691336727, 0.304413384239457, 0.91894460806156, 0.599706795271625, 
0.642673149573306, -0.412565627467277, 0.672207513790216, 0.967040903075167, 
0.468047601527563, 0.637785901287577, 0.844643267672228, 0.531304065337568, 
0.871382716325882, 0.652137447647579, 0.39953254735831, 0.683918734842367, 
0.64113649695194, -1.12087270379329, 0.627669809872133, 0.294456709215146, 
0.539711347678816, 0.710504348497859, 0.346598697399641, -1.07632639234637, 
-1.09963086428893, -1.09739189778582, -1.13930502605998, -0.748393619076803
), .Dim = c(5L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("dDomingo", "dSegunda", 
"dTerça", "dQuarta", "dQuinta", "dSexta", "dSábado")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the `matrix` to `data frame` first. Then use `tidyr::gather` to convert to long format

```r
mat1 <- structure(c(-1.78355763661757, -1.73008589314791, -1.50333251627705, 
  -1.72026078275706, -1.23470060199216, 0.512322374645035, 0.855268450002498, 
  0.945016691336727, 0.304413384239457, 0.91894460806156, 0.599706795271625, 
  0.642673149573306, -0.412565627467277, 0.672207513790216, 0.967040903075167, 
  0.468047601527563, 0.637785901287577, 0.844643267672228, 0.531304065337568, 
  0.871382716325882, 0.652137447647579, 0.39953254735831, 0.683918734842367, 
  0.64113649695194, -1.12087270379329, 0.627669809872133, 0.294456709215146, 
  0.539711347678816, 0.710504348497859, 0.346598697399641, -1.07632639234637, 
  -1.09963086428893, -1.09739189778582, -1.13930502605998, -0.748393619076803
  ), .Dim = c(5L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("dDomingo", "dSegunda", 
  "dTerça", "dQuarta", "dQuinta", "dSexta", "dSábado")))

df <- data.frame(mat1)

library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  gather(key, value)

#>         key      value
#> 1  dDomingo -1.7835576
#> 2  dDomingo -1.7300859
#> 3  dDomingo -1.5033325
#> 4  dDomingo -1.7202608
#> 5  dDomingo -1.2347006
#> 6  dSegunda  0.5123224
#> 7  dSegunda  0.8552685
#> 8  dSegunda  0.9450167
#> 35  dSábado -0.7483936

# rename to whatever you want
df %>% 
  gather(key = "V1", value = "V2")

#>          V1         V2
#> 1  dDomingo -1.7835576
#> 2  dDomingo -1.7300859
#> 3  dDomingo -1.5033325
#> 4  dDomingo -1.7202608
#> 5  dDomingo -1.2347006
#> 6  dSegunda  0.5123224
#> 7  dSegunda  0.8552685
#> 8  dSegunda  0.9450167
#> 35  dSábado -0.7483936
```

**Edit**: to go back to the `wide` format, use `tidyr::spread`

```r
library(dplyr)

df_long %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>% 
  spread(key, value) %>% 
  select(-rowid)

  dDomingo dSegunda dTerça dQuarta dQuinta dSexta dSábado
     <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1    -1.78    0.512  0.600   0.468   0.652  0.628  -1.08 
2    -1.73    0.855  0.643   0.638   0.400  0.294  -1.10 
3    -1.50    0.945 -0.413   0.845   0.684  0.540  -1.10 
4    -1.72    0.304  0.672   0.531   0.641  0.711  -1.14 
5    -1.23    0.919  0.967   0.871  -1.12   0.347  -0.748
```

Created on 2018-04-15 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: And, what is the function I would use to go back?

Answer (score 2):

Using `m` in the Note at the end this base code

```
stack(as.data.frame(m))
```

or this

```
library(zoo)
fortify.zoo(zoo(m), melt = TRUE)
```

will create a two column data frame with 35 rows; however, note that `autoplot.zoo` will plot a multivariate zoo time series using ggplot2 without requiring any explicit transformation.  Remove `facet = NULL` if you want each series in a separate panel.  See `?autoplot.zoo` and `?fortify.zoo` for more info and examples.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

autoplot(zoo(m), facet = NULL) + ggtitle("My Series") + xlab("")
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

We assume that the input `m` is:

```
m <- structure(c(-1.78355763661757, -1.73008589314791, -1.50333251627705, 
-1.72026078275706, -1.23470060199216, 0.512322374645035, 0.855268450002498, 
0.945016691336727, 0.304413384239457, 0.91894460806156, 0.599706795271625, 
0.642673149573306, -0.412565627467277, 0.672207513790216, 0.967040903075167, 
0.468047601527563, 0.637785901287577, 0.844643267672228, 0.531304065337568, 
0.871382716325882, 0.652137447647579, 0.39953254735831, 0.683918734842367, 
0.64113649695194, -1.12087270379329, 0.627669809872133, 0.294456709215146, 
0.539711347678816, 0.710504348497859, 0.346598697399641, -1.07632639234637, 
-1.09963086428893, -1.09739189778582, -1.13930502605998, -0.748393619076803
), .Dim = c(5L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("dDomingo", "dSegunda", 
"dTerça", "dQuarta", "dQuinta", "dSexta", "dSábado")))
```

Answer (score -1):

t(your structure here)

```
t(structure(c(-1.78355763661757, -1.73008589314791, -1.50333251627705, 
-1.72026078275706, -1.23470060199216, 0.512322374645035, 0.855268450002498, 
0.945016691336727, 0.304413384239457, 0.91894460806156, 0.599706795271625, 
0.642673149573306, -0.412565627467277, 0.672207513790216, 0.967040903075167, 
0.468047601527563, 0.637785901287577, 0.844643267672228, 0.531304065337568, 
0.871382716325882, 0.652137447647579, 0.39953254735831, 0.683918734842367, 
0.64113649695194, -1.12087270379329, 0.627669809872133, 0.294456709215146, 
0.539711347678816, 0.710504348497859, 0.346598697399641, -1.07632639234637, 
-1.09963086428893, -1.09739189778582, -1.13930502605998, -0.748393619076803
), .Dim = c(5L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("dDomingo", "dSegunda", 
"dTerça", "dQuarta", "dQuinta", "dSexta", "dSábado"))))
```

output

```
              [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
dDomingo -1.7835576 -1.7300859 -1.5033325 -1.7202608 -1.2347006
dSegunda  0.5123224  0.8552685  0.9450167  0.3044134  0.9189446
dTerça    0.5997068  0.6426731 -0.4125656  0.6722075  0.9670409
dQuarta   0.4680476  0.6377859  0.8446433  0.5313041  0.8713827
dQuinta   0.6521374  0.3995325  0.6839187  0.6411365 -1.1208727
dSexta    0.6276698  0.2944567  0.5397113  0.7105043  0.3465987
dSábado  -1.0763264 -1.0996309 -1.0973919 -1.1393050 -0.7483936
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't express me well. I would like to have a two column matrix. In it, the first column will contain the variable value and the second the variable name, from the last matrix.

Comment: @theBotelho You cannot do that. All elements in a matrix need to be in the same type. You can have numeric and character elements together.